# Can I allow audio from only Spotify during Do Not Disturb?

Tags: settings, spotify, do-not-disturb

I've started listening to music on spotify with the sleep timer as I go to sleep. However, I normally have Do Not Disturb enabled when I sleep, and Do Not Disturb blocks all media because I have the "Media sounds" setting setting to not be able to interrupt. I don't want to enabled this setting because I don't want things like text messages to ding during the night.

I see there is a way to allow notifications from specific apps through Do Not Disturb, but is there a way to allow audio from specific apps? Specifically, I'd like Spotify to be able to play when I have Do Not Disturb up, and nothing else.

I'm running Android 13.

Answer (score -1):

You can control which Apps can break the "Do Not Disturb"

- Open Settings
- Search for  `Disturb`
- Select `do not disturb`
- Select `App notifications`
- Select `Add apps`
- Select `Spotify`

Comment: This only applies to notifications, not Media; meaning, not the music that spotify is actually playing.